# Filter a map by two conditions in Terraform

Tags: for-loop, terraform

Having this input variable

```
variable "input_var"{
  type = map(object({
    str_attribute = string
    num_attribute = number
    sub_obj = optional(object({
      id = number
      other_property = string
    }))
  }))
}
```

How can I loop over all map elements and filter them while taking only the ones that complies to both `sub_obj != null` `and` `id != 0`? And how to make it a map where I keep both the original key and value?

I have tried several things but nothing usable. Latest iteration is:

```
for_each = [for k,v in var.input_var: tomap({k = v}) if v.sub_obj.id !=0]
```

This does not work first because if `sub_obj` is null an error occurs and I was unable to find any information about logical operators, like `and` in this case, such that I could use it as `sub_obj != null and sub_obj.id !=0`.

And second because it does not create a map, which makes sense as `tomap` would create a map from all objects added as arguments.

Comment: Try with `(sub_obj != null && sub_obj.id !=0)`.

Comment: Logical operators: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/operators

Comment: @MarkoE comment --> answer. Also maybe you can do `if coalesce(sub_obj.id, 0) != 0`, or `if try(sub_obj.id != 0, false)`, or other fun variations.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers. The conditional issue should be covered. How to create a map out of the for loop?

Comment: You use the map type constructor as per normal e.g. `{}`. You are currently using the list type constructor instead. Docs for populating the constructor in the manner you are using are at: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/for

Comment: the `&&` operator did not work as expected; it still returned error if null. So the solution was: `for_each = { for k, v in var.input_var: k => v if try(v.sub_obj.id != 0, false) }`

Comment: @MattSchuchard if you want to add this as an answer I would be delighted to mark it as solved, since you provided working solutions for both my questions.

Comment: @MarkoE don't know why it still complained about the `sub_obj` being null and no attribute id exists; it would have make sense to stop the evaluation after first being false. All in all, thanks for your answer as you helped adding new knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To construct a `map` instead of a `list` you should use the constructor `{}`.

For a safe check on the value of `var.input_var.sub_obj.id` inequality with 0, you can use the `coalesce` (similar to null coalescing operators) or `try` functions.

Combining the two we arrive at:

```
# option one
for_each = { for k,v in var.input_var: k => v if coalesce(sub_obj.id, 0) != 0 }
# option two
for_each = { for k,v in var.input_var: k => v if try(sub_obj.id != 0, false) }
```